# @React-native-community/react-native-device-info: NativeModule.RNDeviceInfo is null. To fix this issue these steps: *Run 'react-native link

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux, react-native-device-info

I just created the app with "react-native init NameProject" and had a Base directory that I use constantly, so when I inserted it, I installed the dependencies and link, it happens to me ... I already deleted the "node_modules" directory, reinstalled, re -linked and nothing seems to solve the problem ...

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Is it trouble in ios??

Answer (score 3):

Try running the command

`react-native link react-native-device-info`

or

`cd ios && pod install && cd ..`

Then try running your project again using whichever command you used to start your application `react-native run-android` or `react-native run-ios` or directly run the app from XCode.

Because starting react-native 0.60.0 or newer, **most but NOT all** libraries can *auto-link* their native modules without running `react-native link package_name`. And from what I've tried myself, since react-native-device-info isn't very actively updating themselves, because there isn't much reason to, <s>they doesn't support the *auto-link* thing</s> (*turns out [they do](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info#linking), but maybe on some project it doesn't work as well? at least it doesn't on mine, and I need to link it manually*).

Actually, the error message itself is already quite descriptive on how to fix your problem if you actually try reading it carefully.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't available for expo anymore, see [this post](https://github.com/react-native-device-info/react-native-device-info/issues/576).

You should be able to replace most common properties with `expo-constants` and `expo-device` instead.

Source: https://forums.expo.dev/t/nativemodule-rndeviceinfo-is-null/35351

Answer (score 2):

for me , I didn't close the previous bundle of app

Answer (score 2):

When I experimented with react-native-device-info I discovered that it only works if you're running it on react-native. If you're running it from expo it will give you an error (`RNDeviceInfo is null`).

My App didn't work because I created using `expo init project-name`
This will always say that it is not linked with react-native-device-info.

Make sure that the project is installed using react-native.

```
$ npm i -g create-react-native-app
$ create-react-native-app my-project
$ cd my-project
```

Then run it on react-native using

```
npm start
```

from https://reactnative.dev/blog/2017/03/13/introducing-create-react-native-app

Alternative for `react-native-device-info` => `expo-device` (https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/device/#devicebrand)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure dependency is linked & rebuild your app after adding the dependency.

Don't forget to run pod install on the iOS folder path.

Answer (score 0):

Press

`command + shift + k`

in Xcode and re run