# Expo / React Native Reading Device Info

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-device-info

is there no way to read serial number using expo. I should be able to read using external packages like [react-native-device-info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-info#getserialnumber) but I can’t do this without expo? because when i install this package i get [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57319268/react-native-community-react-native-device-info-nativemodule-rndeviceinfo-is-n) and similar errors. I tried react-native link solution but it didn't work. I need to use expo for other reasons so I can't eject it. There is no part in expo device and constants where I can read these properties.

Answer (score 0):

`react-native-device-info` depends on platform-specific native modules which will not link and compiled with the Expo Go client.

Expo SDK provides a  compatible alternative package to use with Expo Go Client -  https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/device/

Comment: I already said that I tried expo device. I couldn't find a solution where I can read the serial number.

Comment: The Expo team has not provided it due no iOS  API for It. on Android you need READ_PHONE_STATE which too dangerous permission. You will need to  convince Google Play review team why your app require that permission  before app get published.

Comment: Serial Number is private information which not reliable to provide for any random app need it